# Trouble with audio in Windows 8

Tags: audio

Recently, my computer has been acting rather strange. All audio is muted and any time I try to watch a Youtube video the player ends up crashing. I can't seem to find anyone who has had a similar problem but I think I may have found some kind of clue: While trying to run a project I made in C++/python for the Panda3d engine I kept on getting these errors:

> AL lib: DoReset: Failed to initialize audio client:0x8889000f
>   :audio(error): alcCreateContext(_device,NULL): Invalid Device
>   :audio(error): OpenALAudioManager: No open device or context

I have no idea what this means as I am not very knowledgeable of computers.

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to say a lot without more details, but it appears as though the computer is not detecting your audio device. Try right clicking on the computer icon in metro, and selecting manage. Go to the device manager and see if there are any devices that have a yellow exclamation point. if they do, install drivers from the vendor. If not try updating your audio drivers, and restarting.